# Оптимизация mSQL

Tags: php

Вывожу количество товара в корзине пользователя, можно ли сократить этот код?

```
function countt()
{
    // Определение количества товаров в корзине пользователя
    $sql = "SELECT    quantity   FROM basket WHERE customer='" . session_id() . "' and goodsid = '9'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count1 = $row["quantity"];

    $sql = "SELECT    quantity   FROM basket WHERE customer='" . session_id() . "' and goodsid = '4'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count2 = $row["quantity"];

    $sql = "SELECT    quantity   FROM basket WHERE customer='" . session_id() . "' and goodsid = '7'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $count3 = $row["quantity"];

    $count = $count1 + $count2 + $count3;
    echo $count;
}
```

Comment: @Андрей2, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Да, поубирайте все пробелы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(quantity) AS count FROM basket WHERE customer='".session_id()."' and goodsid IN('9', '4', '7')"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row["count"] ;
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно одного селекта. Кроме того, стоит использовать подготавливаемые запросы.

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM basket WHERE customer = ? AND goodsid IN ('9', '4', '7')
```